# How to allow and parse FIX message with QuickFIX if Field 55 appears multiple times in FIX incoming message?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

This particular broker does not provide a DataDictionary so I have to create my own based on their documentation.

This is how they send a particular message:

> FIX.4.4|9=709|35=y|34=53|49=DUMMYBROKER|56=<client_ID>|52=20210211-
> 12:12:37.358847|55=AUD/CAD|55=AUD/CHF|55=AUD/JPY|55=AUD/NZD|55=AUD/USD|55=
> CAD/CHF|55=CAD/JPY|55=CHF/JPY|55=EUR/AUD|55=EUR/CAD|55=EUR/CHF| ...
> etc

- How can I allow QuickFix a field to appear multiple times?
- Once I recieve the message what is the best way to read it? I am using QuickFIX/n.

This would probably provide me the last symbol only:

```
var symbolstring = message.GetString(Tags.Symbol);
```

This is how the SecurityList is defined in the DataDictionary:

```
<message name="SecurityList" msgtype="y" msgcat="app">
    <group name="NoMDEntries" required="Y">
        <field name="Symbol" required="N"/>
    </group>
</message>
```

I have tried changing "Y"/"N" in all variations, but it still cannot absorb the message properly.

Comment: I'm not sure it would work but you could try a repeating group. There should be a e.g. `146=3` tag like the examples on [here](https://gainfutures.com/GFAPI/html/0f30696e-680b-40a1-b935-1bdfbd9dd14d.htm).

Comment: I agree @Shoejep, but there isn't so I am not even sure if it is valid this way but this is how they send it.

Comment: Ask them what are they playing at ;)

Comment: No, they were quite generous with me. I am trying to build a good relationship with them. Instead I might just forward them your comment. :-D

Comment: It is definitely ***not*** a valid FIX message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is invalid FIX, and is simply not parseable by QuickFIX/n (or any QF engine).

A repeating group must start with a counter field which tells the receiver how many instances of that group will follow.  Their message doesn't have that counter field.

Comment: Thank you @Grant Birchmeier, it is great to see that someone from Connamara has also confirm it. I will let them know about the issue.